# A phrase of providing a non-committal answer

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase or saying, used in politics or business, where people respond to questions using non-committal answers.  These answers would be provided to avoid responsibility or ownership of their response and are often "double sided."

As an example:

"I need to do A or B, which should I do?"

"A is very important and should be done, but B is also very valuable and should be taken into consideration"

Comment: Maybe *[equivocate](http://www.onelook.com/?w=equivocate&ls=a&loc=home_ac_ewuivo)* or [prevaricate](http://www.onelook.com/?w=prevaricate&ls=a&loc=home_ac_ewuivo)? Most understandable to modern speakers would be simply a *nonanswer*.

Comment: Equivocate is the best word imo. It's speaking in an intentionally vague and open-ended, non-committal manner.

Comment: Tolkien invented a proverb. He's one person I wouldn't argue with in this department (were he still alive). 'Go not to the Elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes'. // More fully: 'And it is also said,' answered Frodo: 'Go not to the Elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes.'

'Is it indeed?' laughed Gildor. 'Elves seldom give unguarded advice, for advice is a dangerous gift, even from the wise to the wise, and all courses may run ill. ' {[henneth-annun.net](http://www.henneth-annun.net/events_view.cfm?evid=1603)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you give a non-committal answer to a question that asks for a straight answer, you're **"beating around the bush"** or **"being evasive"**

> **beat around the bush** - "to avoid answering a question; to stall; to waste time." [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+around+the+bush)

"Stop beating around the bush and give me a straight answer."

> **evasive** - "intentionally vague or ambiguous; equivocal, avoiding the issue; not straightforward" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evasive)

"As Williams' career progressed, his work became less and less evasive with regard to homosexual themes."

"You have to face the problem head-on and stepping right through it rather than being evasive and hiding from it in the hopes that it'll go away."

Comment: If you explain why the downvote, I can always improve the answer or correct whatever I've missed.

Comment: I can't speak for whoever downvoted you, but I don't see anything wrong with your answer. I would avoid using "evasive", though, as it's too broad. What the OP describes is a specific type of evasion--evasion in _speech_, aka equivocation, prevarication, or any synonym variant of those two words.

Comment: Your answer seems to me to dress the OP's question quite nicely, especially in politics. +1

Comment: A humourous phrase used in the UK is "prevaricate around the bush". I think it came from a character in a TV show, but have heard it used in different settings.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you've mentioned politics or business, how about **sidestep**?

From Dictionary.com:

> [**sidestep**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sidestep?s=ts): to
>   evade or avoid (a decision, problem, or the like)

Your example:

> Person A: "I need to do A or B, which should I do?"
>
> Person B: "A is very important and should be done, but B is also very valuable
>   and should be taken into consideration"

Person B is **sidestepping** Person A's question -- that is, evading or avoiding answering it -- perhaps "to avoid responsibility or ownership of their response". Politicians, especially, do this sort of thing all the time.

Answer (score 1):

A colloquial way of describing someone responding like this is to say they are [sitting on the fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitting_on_the_fence).

Comment: I disagree. Sitting on the fence (or being "on the fence" about something) implies _ambivalence_, not intentionally avoiding giving a committed answer. I could be ambivalent and give a non-committal response, but I could give a non-committal response and not necessarily be ambivalent about the subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

*Two-faced*: adj., deceitful or hypocritical (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/two-faced)

*doublespeak*: noun, evasive, ambiguous language that is intended to deceive or confuse (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/doublespeak?s=t)

You can also say *double talk* but I think that is less well known.